# problem involving logarithmic series

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Show that$$ln(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=1-\frac{1}{2(n+1)}-\frac{1}{2.3(n+1)^2}-\frac{1}{3.4(n+1)^3}-....$$ using logarithmic series.

I try to bring the RHS in the format of logarithmic series but I can't able to do it.

So I try to use binomial theorem on LHS then expand it but I am again fail.

Please someone give hint to solve it .thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\dfrac1{r(r+1)(n+1)^r}=\dfrac{r+1-r}{r(r+1)(n+1)^r}$$ $$=\dfrac{1/(n+1)^r}r-(n+1)\cdot\dfrac{1/(n+1)^{r+1}}{r+1}$$

$$\implies\sum_{r=1}^\infty\dfrac1{r(r+1)(n+1)^r}=\sum_{r=1}^\infty\dfrac{1/(n+1)^r}r-(n+1)\sum_{r=1}^\infty\dfrac{1/(n+1)^{r+1}}{r+1}$$

$$=-\ln\left(1-\dfrac1{n+1}\right)-(n+1)\left\{-\ln\left(1-\dfrac1{n+1}\right)+\dfrac1{n+1}\right\}$$

$$=?$$

as $\ln(1-y)=-\sum_{r=1}^\infty\dfrac{y^r}r$

Comment: Sir is there any error in RHS of the problem?

Comment: I think every term in the RHS of the series is positive am I right sir?

Comment: ...thanks for ur answer it is very helpful sir....but is the RHS of the each term in problem is  positive?

Comment: @Sathasivam, multiply both sides of the last line by $-1$

Answer (score 3):

Letting $x=\frac{1}{n+1}$ then $1+\frac 1n= \frac{1}{1-x}$.

So $$\begin{align}\log(1+1/n)^n &= n\log(1+1/n)\\
&=-\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)\log (1-x)\end{align}$$

Then use that $$-\log(1-x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k}$$

---

**Hint for the last step**: If $f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_kx^k$ then show $$\left(\frac 1x-1\right)f(x)=a_1 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(a_{k+1}-a_k)x^k$$

Comment: Now on simplify I have $$-n(\frac{1}{(n+1)}+\frac{1}{2(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{3(n+1)^3}+...)$$ but how I get answer sir

Comment: Keep it in terms of $x$ a bit longer, @SathasivamK

Comment: Sir please explain it I'm only a beginner in this chapter

Comment: I try as you told if I can't able to do then I ask u later sir@sir@Thomas Andrew

Comment: Thanks sir ..very nice answer it very helpful sir .

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$\ln\left(1+\dfrac1n\right)^n=n\ln\left(1+\dfrac1n\right)=(n+1)\ln\left(1+\dfrac1n\right)-\ln\left(1+\dfrac1n\right)$$

and
$$\ln\left(1+\dfrac1n\right)=-\ln\left(1-\dfrac1{n+1}\right)$$

Now use $\ln(1-y)=-\sum_{r=1}^\infty\dfrac{y^r}r$